# Display items of a dictionary to labels one by one on button click in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

I have two scenes in my project. In the first one, the user inputs two values, and those values are added to the dictionary `words` having `input1` as the key and `input2` as the value:

```
var words = [String: String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var input2: UITextField!

@IBAction func add(_ sender: UIButton) {
  if (input.text != "") {
     words = [input.text: input2.text] as! [String : String]
  }
}
```

And in the second one, I want to make it so that all the pairs of values that were added in the previous scene will be displayed on two labels one by one on the button click.

so far I've got only this:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var word1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var word2: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    for data in words{
        let key1 = data.key
        let value1 = data.value
        word1.text = key1
        word2.text = value1
    }
  }
}
```

And it only displays the last values of the added words when the screen loads...

And also, a question, is the method that I am using to save the user input values even correct? Does it actually add new values after another or does it only rewrite the first added one?

visual representation:
[image: visual representation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Let me do little bit changes in your code.

**First** , Replace

```
var words = [String: String]()
```

with

```
var words = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
```

**Second** , Replace your add button functionality to this -

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if (input.text != "") {

         words.append([input.text: input2.text] as! [String : String])
         input.text = ""
         input2.text = ""
     }
}
```

**Third** , Add this line in your `secondViewContoller` -

```
var wordIndex = 0
```

**Fourth** , Remove your code in `viewDidAppear` and add this line -

```
showValue()
```

**Now define this method**

```
private func showValue(){

    if wordIndex < words.count {

        if let word = words[wordIndex] as? Dictionary<String, String> {
            word1.text = word.keys.first
            word2.text = word.values.first

        }

    }else{
        debugPrint("No more words!")
    }
}
```

**Now, time to add Next button action to see next word** , So here we go -

```
@IBAction func btnActionNext(_ sender: UIButton) {

    wordIndex += 1
    showValue()

}
```

**We are done now.** :)

Let me know if you are still having any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use array of words to save every inputs to words as array of dictionary. Then only you can able to show all items on scene2

`var words = [[String: String]]()`

Here Dont save a value to words.

Insert a value to words

`let value = ["key":"value"]
 words.append(value)`

Then pass a words to next scene.
show each keys and values by below format

```
var buttonClickCount: Int = 0
let showWord = words[buttonClickCount]
//print this word while clicking button
```

Comment: oh, that's great!! but how can I show the added values one by one on button click? I'm sorry, my knowledge in swift is very little

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work: `words.insert([input.text:input2.text])` the error says, Missing argument for parameter 'at' in call

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can check and follow the same based on button click count

Comment: somehow any of this doesn't work for me. have you tried this on your computer? i get a lot of error messages such as `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Int'`, `Missing argument for parameter 'at' in cal` and the following. what should i do?

Comment: You can use append function to add new element. Updated check it below